# application.worksheetfunction.sum not evaluating string

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have the following code in my procedure built up to be evaluated within a much larger loop

```
CalculationHoldArray(Loopcount) = "'[" & Usefile1.Name & "]" & _ 
                 Worksheet1 & "'!" & Cells1      & ",'[" & Usefile2.Name & "]" & _ 
                 Worksheet2 & "'!" & Cells2

Sheets("ECAP PARAMETER INPUTS").Cells(31, "F").Value = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(CalculationHoldArray(Loopcount))
```

The string returned for the array is:

```
'[Control Model v1.35- nonfunctional.xlsm]Input'!E2, _
      '[Control Model v1.35- nonfunctional.xlsm]Input'!E3
```

But the application.worksheetfunction.sum is returning an error 1004. "Unable to get the sum property of the worksheet class".  Anyone know what the issue is that it won't let me use the sum property here?

Comment: `1.`Can you show us the declarations of your variables used in this code? e.g. `LoopCount` and so on.. `2.` Why is that you want to set book, sheet, cell references in this manner instead of using `R1C1` formula or `range offsets`?

Comment: Loopcount is defined as a double, usefile1 and usefile2 as workbooks, worksheet1 and worksheet2 as string, cells1 and cells 2 as string, calculationholdarray as an array of 15 string elements.       Why am I setting in this way?  Mainly because I have been out of programming for 15 years, got retrenched from the bank and now I am doing some contract work to try and make ends meet.  Just using the way I used to do it and have never learned how to use R1C1 referencing properly

Comment: Looking at your cell string, you are getting data from same workbook, same sheet Row `E2, E3`. But your variables are showing `UserFile1` and `UserFile2` --> rather two files. So what are you looping to populate the Array? Two different files or single file/workbook?

Comment: A single worksheet- but the cells to create the formulae are built up from a choice form 5 different files- thus why they are variable names.  It would be a lot easier if the data to be used was all in one place, sadly that is not the case.

Comment: But I have found a solution- instead of using the application.worksheet.function command, I can simply use the "EVALUATE" command, just required adding in the "sum" and brackets to make it a full formulae

Comment: @MarcL submit it as your own answer - you'll be able to accept it after a day or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I have found a solution- instead of using the application.worksheet.function command, I can simply use the "EVALUATE" command, just required adding in the "sum" and brackets to make it a full formulae –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Application.Worksheet.Function` command, simply use the `Evaluate` command, which requires adding in the "sum" and brackets to make it a valid formulae.